# Is it possible to forward subtractMonth() function of react native calendars to a different component like a button?

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

I'm building a calendar page for an app and want the month and month change arrows to be displayed next to the calendar rather than on top of it. So I have removed the header component created a View component next to it. However I am unable to figure out how to change the month when the next month button is pressed.

[Here is an image of the screen for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWI9x.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably using refs

```
const calendarRef = React.useRef()
<Calendar ref={calendarRef}/>
```

Now you can pass the calendarRef to other components and use this

```
calendarRef.addMonth(-1)
```

Note : Found it here https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/issues/764

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly! I spent way too much time on this, thank you so much!

Comment: Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()? @keysl